# Dos programming using C++/STL and curl and openssl libraries

Tags: curl, openssl, dos

I’m newbie in DOS-programming and now I have a task to develop some application providing SOAP-requests realization. I have already developed the same application under Linux, using C++/STL and curl and openssl libraries. Is there any way to use all of this ( C++/STL and curl and openssl libraries) in DOS  (to be more exact DOS 6. 22) ? 
Could you also give me some recommendation how can I install Norton Commander or another one at pure console DOS version (Virtual Box) and share files between host Windows and guest DOS systems. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maria - this is probably going to be closed as too broad. Perhaps the person who tasked you could give you some guidance. Come back when you have a specific programming question.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry! But may be somebody had the similar task and can give а good advice. I can refine my questions:
1) Are there such tools, as C++/STL, curl and openssl libraries  in DOS 6. 22?
2) How can I organize connection between Windows host and DOS guest systems. I’ve read that there is no VMware and Virtual Box guest additions for DOS…

Comment: Maria - I think you'll have better luck with a question like this over in the SuperUser SE site at http://superuser.com.